# Translate website without duplicate custom post

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, translation, plugin-polylang

I have a website where anyone can post **jobs** from frontend. The **jobs** pages are rendered by custom archive and single pages in my custom theme.

I want the website to be multi language with switcher. The problem is to translate the static text in *archive-job.php* and *singe-job.php*, without translating the content of **jobs**.

I tried polylang, but that one needs multiple posts, one for each language. Which means that I need to duplicate the post content

Is there a way to assign multiple languages to same post, without creating redundant posts in polylang (or a free alternative, excepting WPML)?

Answer (score 0):

You could create one post with each language variation wrapped in a custom tag. You would need to create a parser then to extract the language you require but it would avoid creating redundant posts like you wished.

For example the post content would be:

```
<eb>This is my post<en><de>Das ist mein Beitrag<de>
```

I currently use WPML and would highly reccomend it!